# Android NDK, Permissions for a pure native app launched using adb

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am implementing a pure native (C++) tool using the NDK, this tool need to be able to access "/dev/graphics/fb0", and for that, I need the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"/>
```

How do I specify permissions for a pure Native C++ app? ( no apk, only exe ) 
How do I implement AndroidManifest.xml? should it get embedded in the Executable in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify permissions for a single executable (since it doesn't have a manifest).

If you run an executable, it will simply inherit the permissions of the userId it is running under. E.g. if you run it with "adb shell", if will run under the "shell" user id, which cannot access the framebuffer.

Your only hope is to do one of the following:

- Root the device and run adb shell as root (either with 'su' or 'adb root' first). This generally cannot be done with regular devices (i.e. those have not been flashed with a custom ROM).
- Create an APK that includes a VM application that will call the executable under its UID. The APK's manifest will list the corresponding permissions.